# Registration gives error "required mobile" but there is no field mobile in the form

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, register

I did not remember what change i have been made now when I want to create new Account it gives this error "mobile is required" and there is no mobile field appeared on registration form please help me someone where I remove mobile field

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that could have happened here.

**You set the mobile number to required but you do not need it to be:**

In this case you can create a setup script that sets the attribute back to not required.

```
$installer->updateAttribute('customer', 'mobile', 'is_required', false);
```

All this is doing is updating the `customer` attribute `mobile` and setting it as not required.

**You have removed the field from the form:**

In the case that the field should be required but should also be in the registration form then you can create a set-up script that adds the attribute to the form.

```
$attribute    = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'mobile');
$currentForms = $attribute->getUsedInForms();
$newForms     = array_unique(array_merge($currentForms, array('customer_account_create')));
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $newForms);
$attribute->save();
```

Once it has been added as being used in the form then you can add this field to your template.